# SOAP class for PHP 4

Tags: php, soap

I need to connect to a webservice via soap, and only realized that the server I need to work on is PHP 4. Are there any good methods to connect to a web service using PHP 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) was once upon a time *the* SOAP implementation for PHP 4. I'm not sure, if they have meanwhile tightened their requirements.